# Find duplicate rows among different groups with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

### Problem

Consider the following dataframe:

```py
data_so = {
        'ID':  [100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300],
        'letter': ['A','B','A','C','D','E','D','A'],
}
df_so = pandas.DataFrame (data_so, columns = ['ID', 'letter'])
```

[image]

I want to obtain a new column where all duplicates **in different groups** are True. All other duplicates in the same group should be False.

### What I've tried

I've tried using

```py
df_so['dup'] = df_so.duplicated(subset=['letter'], keep=False)
```

but the result is not what I want:

[image]

The first occurrence of A in group 1 (row 0) is `True` because there is a duplicate in another group (row 7). However all *other* occurrences of A in the same group (row 2) should be `False`.

If row 7 is deleted, then row 0 should be `False` because A is not present anymore in any other group.

Comment: The "A" in row 2 also has a duplicate in row 7 though?  Why isn't row 0 A also False then?

Comment: The first occurrence of A in group 1 (row 0) is true because there is a duplicate in another group (row 7). However all other occurrences of A in the same group (row 2) should be false.

Comment: Do you need to mark them as true/false or could you just remove the false ones? If you can just remove this is a bit easier

Comment: @noah I need to mark them as true or false without removing any row

Comment: what if the data has `row=8, letter=A` what is its value?

Comment: @AndyL. if the data has `row=8, ID=300, letter=A` then the value is `False` because A is already present in group 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is essentially the `AND` of two different `duplicated()` calls.

1. `~df_so.duplicated()` deals within groups
2. `df_so.drop_duplicates().duplicated(subset='letter',keep=False).fillna(True)` Deals between groups ignoring current group duplicates

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
data_so = { 'ID':  [100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300], 'letter': ['A','B','A','C','D','E','D','A'], }
df_so = pd.DataFrame (data_so, columns = ['ID', 'letter'])
df_so['dup'] = ~df_so.duplicated() & df_so.drop_duplicates().duplicated(subset='letter',keep=False).fillna(True)
print(df_so)
```

Output:

```
    ID letter    dup
0  100      A   True
1  100      B  False
2  100      A  False
3  200      C  False
4  200      D   True
5  300      E  False
6  300      D   True
7  300      A   True
```

Other case:

```
data_so = { 'ID':  [100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300], 'letter': ['A','B','A','C','D','E','D'] }
```

Output:

```
    ID letter    dup
0  100      A  False
1  100      B  False
2  100      A  False
3  200      C  False
4  200      D   True
5  300      E  False
6  300      D   True
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the best solution in my opinion

Comment: @Ford1892 to change you just need to adjust ```subset=['letter','param2']``` to include all columns that you care about. The ```duplicated()``` call with the subset param is dealing with overall duplicates with the ```~duplicated()``` call is dealing within groups. So should be easy to adjust as per your comment on Andy's answer

Comment: Thanks, but I found a problem with your solution: if we remove row 7, then row 0 should be False, because there wouldn't be any duplicates of A in the other groups

Comment: hmm. I'll take a look in a bit and get back to you with a fix

Comment: @AndyL. it returns ```False``` when I run it

Comment: I stand corrected. It returns `False`, my sample has additional columns `dup` from previous testing, ` ~df_so.duplicated()` returns diff result.

Comment: @Ford1892: my `df_so` has more columns so result is different. please disregard all my comments above.

Comment: @AndyL. The problem occurs when A is present only in the first group. In this case, A should be False because there aren't duplicates of A in other groups

Comment: I'm talking about this case (sorry for bad formatting):
```data_so = { 'ID':  [100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300], 'letter': ['A','B','A','C','D','E','D'] }
df_so = pandas.DataFrame (data_so, columns = ['ID', 'letter'])```

Comment: @Ford1892 fixed?

Comment: @Ford1892 when I run it I am getting False. I included what I think is the correct case in my answer. Am I using an incorrect case?

Comment: @Ford1892 just realized one of the three duplicated() calls is unnecessary. See updated code.

Comment: @noah I didn't see your edit, that is indeed correct, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

As you clarify in the comment, you need an additional mask beside current `duplicated`

```
m1 = df_so.duplicated(subset=['letter'], keep=False)
m2 = ~df_so.groupby('ID').letter.apply(lambda x: x.duplicated())

df_so['dup'] = m1 & m2

Out[157]:
    ID letter    dup
0  100      A   True
1  100      B  False
2  100      A  False
3  200      C  False
4  200      D   True
5  300      E  False
6  300      D   True
7  300      A   True
8  300      A  False
```

**Note**: I added `row=8` as in the comment.

Comment: If you remove rows 7 and 8, then A should be False because because there wouldn't be any duplicates of A in the other groups

Answer (score 0):

My idea for this problem:

```
import datatable as dt

df = dt.Frame(df_so)

df[:1, :, dt.by("ID", "letter")]
```

I would group by both the ID and letter column. Then simply select the first row.