# Pandas duplicate rows among all the different groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Consider the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO 
data = StringIO(""",ID,action,url_host,url
    0,100,link,www.apple.com,https://www.apple.com/
    1,100,clickLink,www.apple.com,https://www.apple.com/
    2,100,link,www.apple.com,https://www.apple.com/iphone/
    3,100,link,www.google.com,https://www.google.com/
    4,100,link,www.google.com,https://www.google.com/?
    5,100,link,9to5mac.com,https://9to5mac.com/
    6,200,link,www.google.com,https://www.google.com/
    7,200,clickTextField,www.google.com,https://www.google.com/
    8,200,formSubmit,www.google.com,https://www.google.com/search?
    9,200,clickTextField,www.google.com,https://www.google.com/search?
    10,200,link,www.macrumors.com,https://www.macrumors.com/
    11,300,link,www.google.com,https://www.google.com/
    12,300,clickTextField,www.google.com,https://www.google.com/
    13,300,link,www.repubblica.it,https://www.repubblica.it/
""")
df_stack = pd.read_csv(data, index_col=0)
```

I want to add a new column denoting **duplicate rows among all the *different* groups**.

A group is composed by all the rows with the same ID. In `df_stack` there are 3 groups.

I only want to consider a subset of columns for identifying duplicates according to the following conditions:

1. if a row is present *at least once* in **ALL** the groups, it is a duplicate
2. if a row is present multiple times ONLY in the same group, it is NOT a duplicate

I tried using

```py
df_stack['duplicated'] = df_stack.duplicated(subset=['action','url_host'], keep=False)
```

but the result is not what I want:

- rows 0,1 should be False because they are NOT present in ALL the other groups
- rows 7,9,12 should be False for the same reason

[image]

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64128529/14366533) doesn't work in this case because it doesn't consider condition 1.

Comment: What do you call a "group"?

Comment: A group is composed by all the rows with the same ID. In this case there are 3 groups. group 1: rows 0-5 - group 2: rows 6-10 - group 3: rows 11-13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) for get counts per `ID` and combinations `url_host, action` - then test only rows with greater like `1` for match at least one value in all groups. Last use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator` parameter for test if match filtered rows in original data:

```
df1 = pd.crosstab([df_stack['url_host'], df_stack['action']], df_stack['ID'])

df1 = (df1.reset_index().loc[df1.gt(0).all(axis=1).to_numpy(), 
                            ['url_host','action']])

mask = df_stack.merge(df1, how='left', indicator=True)['_merge'].eq('both')
df_stack['duplicated'] = mask

with pd.option_context('display.expand_frame_repr', False):
    print (df_stack)
     ID          action           url_host                             url  duplicated
0   100            link      www.apple.com          https://www.apple.com/       False
1   100       clickLink      www.apple.com          https://www.apple.com/       False
2   100            link      www.apple.com   https://www.apple.com/iphone/       False
3   100            link     www.google.com         https://www.google.com/        True
4   100            link     www.google.com        https://www.google.com/?        True
5   100            link        9to5mac.com            https://9to5mac.com/       False
6   200            link     www.google.com         https://www.google.com/        True
7   200  clickTextField     www.google.com         https://www.google.com/       False
8   200      formSubmit     www.google.com  https://www.google.com/search?       False
9   200  clickTextField     www.google.com  https://www.google.com/search?       False
10  200            link  www.macrumors.com      https://www.macrumors.com/       False
11  300            link     www.google.com         https://www.google.com/        True
12  300  clickTextField     www.google.com         https://www.google.com/       False
13  300            link  www.repubblica.it      https://www.repubblica.it/       False
```