# Pandas: how to add column with Booleans (True/False) based on duplicates in one column and group index in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
d_test = {
    'name' : ['bob', 'rob', 'dan', 'steeve', 'carl', 'steeve', 'dan', 'carl', 'bob'],
    'group': [1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 5]
}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(d_test)
```

I am looking for a way to add column `duplicate` with `True`/`False` for each entry. I want `True` only for case if there is more than one duplicate from 'name' that belongs more than one 'group' number. Here is expected output:

```
    name    group   duplicate
0   bob     1       True
1   rob     4       False
2   dan     3       True
3   steeve  3       False
4   carl    2       True
5   steeve  3       False
6   dan     2       True
7   carl    1       True
8   bob     5       True
```

For example above, row `0` has `True` in `duplicate` because `name` is the same as in row `8` and `group` number is different (`1` and `5`). Row `3` has `False` in `duplicate` because no duplicates exist outside of the same group `3`.

Comment: What does mean `Row 3 has False in duplicate because no duplicates exist outside of the same group 3.` ?

Comment: @jezrael we have two Steeves. Row 3 and 5. If we would not have `group` column then we would get `True` for it because it is duplicate.  But for this case it is not because we consider entity a duplicate only if it is outside of one group

Comment: But why is dan False?

Comment: [Likely what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64128529/find-duplicate-rows-among-different-groups-with-pandas)

Comment: @illuminato plz chk code and output before asking

Comment: @PandaKim sorry, fixed code

Comment: @jezrael my mistake. it should be True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong in your example, Perhaps what you want is possible with following code

```
result = df_test.groupby('name')['group'].transform(lambda x: x.nunique() > 1)
df_test.assign(duplicated=result)
```

output(`df_test.assign(duplicated=result`):
:

```
    name    group   duplicated
0   bob     1       True
1   rob     4       False
2   dan     3       True
3   steeve  3       False
4   carl    2       True
5   steeve  3       False
6   dan     2       True
7   carl    1       True
8   bob     5       True
```

Comment: @jezrael  anyway code and output text are different. I think there are something wrong. and i think he want this